# How should I remove duplicate content caused by URL parameters that's already been indexed by google?

Tags: google-search-console, duplicate-content, rel-canonical

On our website, we have many "project" pages with a similar URL structure.

Ex: acme.com/projects/unique-project-title

Another site that backlinks to us uses utm parameters (and we want them to) when pointing to our project pages.

**Ex: acme.com/projects/unique-project-title?utm_campaign=sister_site**

This last type of URL has already been indexed on Google.

Since we noticed the problem, we have added a canonical link so that Google will know to not index the URLs with UTM parameters in the future.

How can I safely remove the currently indexed UTM param URLs, and only have the correct "original" URLs indexed?

We are using a Domain Property on Google Search Console and therefore cannot use the URL Parameter tool.

- Should we remove the incorrect URLs via the removal tool?

Worried that doing may cause a gap in coverage or remove our search results.
We have already submitted a sitemap with only the correct URLs but not sure how long that will take to be fully crawled.

Comment: See also: [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site). TL;DR Google won't penalize your site for duplicate content, Google just chooses one of the duplicate URLs to index.